Is there any animal with seven eyes?
Lots of animals have no eyes at all. Among animals with eyes, the number is quite variable. Defining eyes broadly to include simple and complex eyes, I can think of examples of animals with any number from one to ten, except seven:

Cyclops
Almost all vertebrates
Triops
Lampreys (two large eyes, two parietal eyes)
Vespids, Opabinia
Recluse spiders
???
Most spiders
Horseshoe crabs (2 compound eyes, 7 simple eyes in various places)
Many species of scorpions

Is there any animal with seven eyes?

Yeah, this is a REALLY open-ended question with no real relevance in biology.
